# DLL working fine in Windows Forms application, which is not working in Web Application

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms, desktop-application

Im facing strange issue at which we are using a custom made dll for fetching Media Information. I was able to refer it in Windows Forms application and its fetching the details of the media. But when its refereed in Web application, its throwing error at runtime says Path is wrong or something like that. But both the path of media I tried was same. What could be the possible reasons.

Comment: You are using something that was build for Windforms in Webforms, which are not the same. But without any code i'ts impossible to say what the issue could be.

Comment: OK.. So we can create DLL just for winforms alone... isnt it? I had no idea about that.. I thought it will work with both...

Comment: Sure you can create it for wind forms alone. But that does not mean you cannot create it for both, as long as you create some methods that are technology specific.

Comment: OK. That sounds possible in this case.. I will check that.. Thanks